# Is water still infinite with BuildCraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft

In Minecraft, when you use a bucket to get water, or you dig out a block on a shore line, most of the time the water around it fills to turn it into a normal water block, this way a small pool of water can be used as an infinite water source (e.g. a 3x3 well with water placed in all 4 corners, the center block will always refill).

With Combustion Engines in the BuildCraft Mod, you can cool them down with water from buckets or through pipes. I am wondering: if I had a block of water which always refilled when I would use a bucket, and I was to draw water from that point with a pipe for a Combustion Engine, would the water still be infinite?

Edit: I do not use Feed The Beast, but I have installed BuildCraft Stable 6.0 manually.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the pump you use. The Redpower pumps suck up water *blocks*, eventually draining a water source entirely, but IndustrialCraft pumps are not so "efficient". They will only empty a single water block, so as long as you have an infinite water source, they will pump the fluid indefinitely. A good way to think about it is an IndustrialCraft pump will function the same way as a bucket - if you have an infinite water source, the pump will continue without issue.

Thermal Expansion have an alternate option, called an Aqueous Accumulator. It's a little expensive to build, but this is the machine you are looking for. All you require is a small infinite water source and the Accumulator will draw from this indefinitely.

[Here is the recipe](http://ftbwiki.org/Aqueous_Accumulator) for the Accumulator.

Comment: i'm looking at the list of [recipes](http://www.mod-buildcraft.com/wiki/doku.php?id=recipes) and can't find anything by that name, could you provide a link?

Comment: i didn't think i needed to indicate as such but is this Aqueous Accumulator available only with Feed the Beast as i don't use it

Comment: Ah yes, It is in Feed the Beast.

Comment: It's thermal expansion, so not everything from FTB is required.

Comment: The water blocks around the Aqueous Accumulator don't even need to be infinite, they just need to be source blocks. The more sides adjacent to source blocks, the more water it creates. It will also create a very small amount of water when not surrounded by any water.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but I use a 5x5x1 pool of water just in case. The engine I use on the pump is the redstone engine. I put pumps in each corner of the 5x5 pool of water.